# parsing javascript codes with php echo

Tags: javascript, php, double-quotes, single-quotes

I want to parsing this code with php echo :

```
<li><a onclick="resource('showvideo',<?= $myvideo->id?>);"> <i class="fa fa-file-video-o"></i>&nbsp; {{$myvideo->title}}</a></li>
```

but results get to this code :

```
<li><a onclick="resource(' showvideo',44);"> <i class="fa fa-file-video-o"></i>&nbsp; test</a></li>
```

I have a new blank space before showvideo in resource parameters!
my php echo :

```
echo "html +="."'<li><a onclick=\"resource(\"showvideo\",44);\"><i class=\"fa fa-file-video-o\"></i>&nbsp;sdfdsf</a></li>'";
```

I try so much to clear this blank space but I failed. please help me

Comment: You can't put double quotes inside double quotes. Try single quotes around `showvideo`. VTC for typo.

Comment: Mixing your PHP, HTML, and JS like this is a mess anyway. Use proper event handlers in separate JS files. If PHP really needs to be involved, just set variable values in the main file, and then use those variables in the JS.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
echo "html +="."'<li><a onclick='resource(&#34;showvideo&#34;,44);\'><i class=\"fa fa-file-video-o\"></i>&nbsp;sdfdsf</a></li>'";
```

And you were getting spaces due to improper use of quotes in your string.

Hope it helps!